# Artifact cannot be resolved from gitlab repository - only in pom.xml, while GET works?

Tags: java, maven

I created a commons artifact in a `gitlab repository`.

I can already download the artifact from within a webbrowser:

```
https://git.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven/com/example/hello-commons/1.0.0/hello-commons-1.0.0.jar
```

But when I try letting `maven` fetch the dependency, I get the following error:

> [WARNING] The POM for com.example:hello-commons:jar:1.0.0 is missing,
> no dependency information available Downloading from gitlab-maven:
> https://git.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven/com/example/hello-commons/1.0.0/hello-commons-1.0.0.jar

This is my `pom.xml`, what might be missing?

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: `The POM for com.example:hello-commons:jar:1.0.0 is missing` -- _is_ the POM present in the repo?

Comment: yes, the `pom.xml` is also present next to the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your local m2 repository (C:\Users\YourUserName.m2\repository) If the folder com/example/hello-commons has been created. If the folder created but download failed it won't retry for a while. Try to delete  that folder and run your maven build again

Comment: Yes, I cleaned the folder, but error remains.

Comment: Sometimes for new repository it takes few hours to become fully available so it is possible for a short time to be able to download from browser and not through maven. But I still think it probably is some cache issue. Try to clear your IDE projects, so your "out" or "classes" folders are cleared and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that a private token has to be set into `~/.m2/settings.xml` as follows:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>PRIVATE_TOKEN_UUID</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

The token must be of scope `read_api`.